# How can I stop the loop exatly when I get the result I want in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I'm trying to solve the TSP with restrictions using the greedy algorithm. I can now get the correct route during the run, but I don't know how to stop the loop exactly when I get the answer. Here is my main code.

```
while repeat_number < nodes_number :
    best_path = 999999999         
    for i in range(nodes_number): 
        if total_distance + distance[city_visited[-1]][i] <= 20000:
            if i not in city_visited and distance[city_visited[-1]][i] != 0 and distance[city_visited[-1]][i] <= best_path:
                best_path = distance[city_visited[-1]][i]
                next_city = i

    city_visited.append(next_city)
    total_distance = total_distance + best_path
     
    repeat_number = repeat_number + 1
```

Through this code, I can find the best solution when the repeat number is 19
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5asUL.png)

However, the loop will continue，causing the final result to be wrong. Therefore, I want to know how to stop this loop once I get my answer. Hope for your help; thank you very much, guys!

Answer (score 0):

You could stop any loop with the `break` command. Just write an `if` Statement, which tests wether the soultion ist good and denn in this Statement call the `break` command.